# iOS App upload stuck at "Authenticating with App Store"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I am uploading iOS application to App Store Connect. It got stuck in authenticating with App Store. I tried Xcode Organizer and Transporter but none of them work for me. This is what it looks like:

[image: Uploading, progress bar, 'Authenticating with the App Store...']

I also attached the screenshot of warning from Apple, is it because of this?

[image: Yellow warning icon, 'Review the updated Paid Applications Schedule.']

Comment: Did you try restarting Xcode? The warning you show above is not related to the upload stalling.

Comment: yes restart XCode, macbook but not work. First line of warning states that in order to update existing apps, create new in-app purchases and submit new apps.  @Norman thats why i am asking